# Piecewise get value at x

Tags: piecewise

I have a piecewise function like this.

```
fP = Piecewise[{{x^2, x < 0}, {x, x > 0}}];
Plot[fFu, {x, -2, 2}]
```

Now I want to **get the y value at a certain x position**, e.g at x=1 the result should be 1.

But when I do

```
Print[fP[1]];
```

I just get the peacewise function itself as output and not the value.

Comment: fP[x_]:=Piecewise...

Comment: That worked now.

Comment: You don't really need `Print`, you can just evaluate `fP[1]` Also see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/8114)

Answer (score 1):

You can allways use Functions (see [How to  Work with Variables and Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithVariablesAndFunctions.html))

```
f[x_] := x^2
Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{f[x], Piecewise[{{f[x], x < 0}, {x, x > 0}}]}, {x, -2, 6}]
```

[image]

```
Piecewise[{{f[x], x < 0}, {x, x > 0}}]
```

[image]

```
f[4]
```

> `16`

```
Piecewise[{{f[4], x < 0}, {x, x > 0}}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{f[x], Piecewise[{{f[x], x < 0}, {x, x > 0}}]}, {x, -2, 6}, 
Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{4, 16}], Dashed, 
Line[{{4, 0}, {4, 16}}], Line[{{0, 16}, {4, 16}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't address the question of how to extract the value from a piecewise function for a given x-value.  You show how to get the value for f[4], when f is not a piecewise function, but that some thing doesn't work when it is.